# Debugging sendmail - dsn=5.0.0

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, sendmail

I am getting alot of the following messages from an ISP when sending out emails. 
Is there any way to get more information from these ? Users are reporting that they are not receiving any emails?

> Jul  5 17:02:50 smtp sendmail[11239]: r6592of7011232: to=, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=168781, relay=mx12.example.com.com. [123.123.123.132], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

Is it possible to start running debug mode for sendmail?

Diden

Comment: The way to get more information is to contact that ISP. In theory, the address `postmaster@example.com` should get an email to the person in charge of email systems, but there's the problem of theory and practice again...

Answer (score 7):

### Sendmail: Sending outgoing test message in verbose/debug mode

As root you may send a test message in verbose mode.
You should get full transcript of SMTP session to the remote SMTP server.

```
(echo: subject: test; echo) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -Am -i user@example.net
```

You may add additional debug/tracking command line options:
`-d8.20` - tracking DNS queuries
`-d60.5` - tracking maps (databases) queries

Comment: I have the same problem and running in verbose mode did not help debug the issue further. The verbose logs actually indicated that the mail was sent. maillog mentions otherwise (stat: Service unavailable)

Comment: @VivekKodira Have you used `-Am` command line option? [I have added it to the answer]

Comment: @Andrej Thank you. Worked with the -Am option and gave a useful response.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Thanks, this really helped me solve this issue!